# SpringBatch: Does a scope job exist

Tags: java, spring, scope, spring-batch

I got the following `batch job`:

```
<batch:job id="importPersonsJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="importPersonStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="personItemReader" writer="personItemWriter"
                commit-interval="5" skip-limit="10">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="java.lang.Throwable" />
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="skipListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="authenticationJobListener" />
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

I need to acces the `JobParameters` in the skipListener as well as in the jobListener. To do this i tried the following:

```
<bean id="skipListener" class="job.batch.listener.Log4JSkipListener" scope="step">
    <property name="logPath" value="#{jobParameters['logPath']}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobListener" class="job.batch.listener.JobListener" scope="job">
    <property name="propertyAccessManager" ref="propertyAccessManager" />
    <property name="logPath" value="#{jobParameters['logPath']}" />
</bean>
```

It seems to work for the skipListener as i get the exception:

```
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'job'
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
 [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 [java]     ... 43 more
```

Doesn't a scope job exist? I found it on this [page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/JobScope.html). Any idea of how to solve my problem? I even tried to use `scope=batch`, which resulted in just the same exception.

Here is the dependency from ivy:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-core" rev="2.1.9.RELEASE" conf="default->default">
    <exclude org="org.aspectj" name="aspectjweaver"/>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a SB version prior to 3.0 (because `scope="job"` is available since this version as @DaveSyer wrote) you can achieve the same result declaring your listener as singleton and do `logPath` parameter extraction in `job.batch.listener.JobListener.beforeJob()`

```
<bean id="jobListener" class="job.batch.listener.JobListener">
    <property name="propertyAccessManager" ref="propertyAccessManager" />
</bean>

class job.batch.listener.JobListener implements JobExecutionListener {
  private String logPath;

  void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("logPath");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link to API docs you posted says "Since 3.0", so I imagine you'll have to be using Spring Batch 3.0 (not yet GA I believe).

Comment: I have added the version i use to my post.

Comment: Where? I can only see schema declarations (mostly old versions where explicit, and nothing specific for batch). You are probably not using Spring 2.5 right?